# Are SUSY transformations free from anomalies?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, quantum-anomalies

Although I've studied supersymmetic field theories for several years, there is a fundamental problem annoying me: *Do SUSY transformations (including both the ordinary ones in various
dimensions and modified ones used for the localization computations)
preserve the path-integral measure in general?*

Related to this (beyond 1-loop but perturbative level), is there any regularizations preserving the supersymmetry? (I've heard that sometimes some commonly used regularizations may break the supersymmetry at higher loop order but I'm not sure.)

I've found some references discussing the latter subject but they are specific and technical things to me. And I do not see any certain cases in literatures. For example, 4D WZ model, 4D maximal SYM or 10D SYM and 4D on $S^4$.
If you know some good references/summary of results, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, $\bar{DR}$ preserves SUSY.

Comment: How general is the answer ? Is it true for various dimensions, for example ? And the statement that DR scheme preserves SUSY is not trivial for me because the property of fermions (or spinors) such as chiralities and Majorana condition depends on the dimension. Is it trivial ? I also wonder why the usual supergraph methods work well with for the same reason.

Comment: I already have thought of a possible [ever]solution! https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/770031/can-this-susy-anomaly-disappear-in-higher-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Not always!

Supersymmetry like any other symmetry can be anomalous.

Here are some specific realistic examples of such scenario:

[Explicit breaking of supersymmetry by non-perturbative effects](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9412186)

[Anomalous Supersymmetry Breaking by Instantons](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506051)

[A Supersymmetry Anomaly](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9612057)

[Feynman rules for non-perturbative sectors and anomalous supersymmetry Ward identities](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9908074)