# Can this SUSY anomaly disappear in higher dimensions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, symmetry-breaking, quantum-anomalies, supergravity

I read this thread of articles by Casher(quite marginal in terms of citation) where they show in certain realistic models SUSY is broken by non-perturbative effects.

[Explicit breaking of supersymmetry by non-perturbative effects](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9412186)

The SUSY currents turn out anomalous.

Now I want to add a twist:

Does the anomaly survive even by addition of extra dimensions?
If so, is the number of such dimensions the same as critical superstring theory? Or Super gravity?